# Angular NgRx action union types errors

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

I have the following code

shared.actions.ts

```
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Error } from '../error.interface';

export const types = {
  IS_LOADING: '[SHARED] IS_LOADING',
  TRIGGER_ERROR: '[SHARED] TRIGGER_ERROR'
}

export class IsLoading implements Action {
  readonly type = types.IS_LOADING;

  constructor(public payload: boolean){}
}

export class TriggerError implements Action {
  readonly type = types.TRIGGER_ERROR;

  constructor(public payload: Error[]){}
}

export type sharedActions = IsLoading | TriggerError;
```

shared.reducer.ts

```
import * as sharedActions from './shared.actions';
import { Error } from '../error.interface';

export interface State {
  isLoading: boolean;
  errors: Error[];
}

const initialState: State = {
  isLoading: false,
  errors: null
}

export function sharedReducer(
  state: State = initialState,
  action: sharedActions.sharedActions
  ): State{
  switch(action.type){
    case sharedActions.types.IS_LOADING:
      return { ...state, isLoading: action.payload } // 1st Error here

    case sharedActions.types.TRIGGER_ERROR:
      return { isLoading: false, errors: action.payload } // 2nd error here

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

I get those errors :

1st error

```
Type 'boolean | Error[]' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
  Type 'Error[]' is not assignable to type 'boolean'
```

2nd error

```
Type 'boolean | Error[]' is not assignable to type 'Error[]'.
  Type 'false' is not assignable to type 'Error[]'.
```

I marked where those errors come from in the code, I really can't tell what I'm doing wrong here.

I'm using Visual Studio Code, I think it might be a bug from the IDE itself.
any thoughts? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You might need enums to check because using const it only gives you string but with enums it differs from each other.

```
export enum ACTIONS {
  IS_LOADING = '[SHARED] IS_LOADING',
  TRIGGER_ERROR = '[SHARED] TRIGGER_ERROR'
}
```

```
export enum ACTIONS {
  IS_LOADING = '[SHARED] IS_LOADING',
  TRIGGER_ERROR = '[SHARED] TRIGGER_ERROR'
}

export class IsLoading implements Action {
  readonly type: ACTIONS.IS_LOADING = ACTIONS.IS_LOADING;

  constructor(public payload: boolean) {}
}

export class TriggerError implements Action {
  readonly type = ACTIONS.TRIGGER_ERROR;

  constructor(public payload: Error[]) {}
}

export type SharedActions = IsLoading | TriggerError;

export interface State {
  isLoading: boolean;
  errors: Error[];
}

const initialState: State = {
  isLoading: false,
  errors: null
};

export function sharedReducer(state: State = initialState, action: SharedActions): State {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ACTIONS.IS_LOADING:
      return { ...state, isLoading: action.payload }; // 1st Error here

    case ACTIONS.TRIGGER_ERROR:
      return { isLoading: false, errors: action.payload }; // 2nd error here

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try `as const` as below:

```js
export const types = {
  IS_LOADING: '[SHARED] IS_LOADING',
  TRIGGER_ERROR: '[SHARED] TRIGGER_ERROR'
} as const;
```